# Snakemake input and output according to a dictionary

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake, wildcard-expansion

I am trying to rename some files in the snakemake pipeline.
Let's say I have three files: `"FileA.txt"`, `"FileB.txt"`, `"FileC.txt"` and I want them renamed according to a dictionary `dict = {"A": "0", "B": "1", "C": "2"}` to get `"RenamedFile0.txt"`, `"RenamedFile1.txt"`, and `"RenamedFile2.txt"`. How would one write a rule for this?

This is how my pipeline looks like (I've tried with a function but doesn't work)

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C"]
RENAMED_SAMPLES = ["0", "1", "2"]

rename = {"0": "A", "1": "B", "2": "C"}

def mapFile(wildcards):
    file = "results/EditedFile" + str(rename[wildcards]) + ".txt"
    return(file)

rule all:
    input:
        "results/Combined.txt"

rule cut:
    input:
        "data/File{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "results/EditedFile{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "cut -f1 {input} > {output}"

rule rename:
    input:
        mapFile
    output:
        "results/RenamedFile{renamedSample}.txt"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"


rule combine:
    input:
        expand("results/RenamedFile{renamedSample}.txt", renamedSample = RENAMED_SAMPLES)
    output:
        "results/Combined.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: ['2']
Wildcards:
renamedSample=2
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

When running a custom expansion, the names of wildcards should be specified:

```py
def mapFile(wildcards):
    file = "results/EditedFile" + rename[wildcards.renamedSample] + ".txt"
    return(file)
```

In this specific case, it's also possible to integrate the logic in the rule itself:

```py
rule rename:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: f"results/EditedFile{rename[wildcards.renamedSample]}.txt"
    output:
        "results/RenamedFile{renamedSample}.txt"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

Comment: A few  other points, though this answers the question.  Generally you don't want to remove files by yourself.  Clearly the rule is called rename, so the expectation is you would call `mv` instead of `cp`, but that would cause problems with the DAG.  If you have a giant file, `cp` will be slow so consider using symbolic links instead.  Finally, the best solution is to call your output what you want to begin with (rule cut here).  I know that's not possible for some tools with pre-defined outputs, but in those cases put your `mv` with the rule that generates the outputs.